# Routine verification of net convergence

Tags: general-topology, nets

Question $1$:

> Suppose that $(D,\le '), (E, \le '')$ are two directed sets where $D \cap E = \varnothing$. We impose an order $\le$ on $D \cup E$ thus: $x \le y \iff  \cases{x, y \in D, x \le′ y \text{ or } \\ x, y \in E, x \le'' y \text{ or } \\  x \in D, y \in  E}$

> When will a net $(x_\gamma)_{\gamma \in D \cup E}$ converge in a space?

Question $2$:

> Suppose that $(x_\gamma)_{\gamma \in D}$ is a convergent net in $(X, \tau)$, where $(D, \le)$ is a directed set. Take any $\gamma_0 \in D$, define $D_0 = \{\gamma \in D: \gamma \ge \gamma_0\}$ and order the elements of $D_0$ by the same order as in $D$. Show the net $(x_\gamma)_{\gamma \in D_0}$ also converges.

Answers:

Let $U$ be a neighborhood of limit $l$.

$1$:

Suppose,

exists $K \in D $ s.t. $k_i \ge K \implies x_{k_i} \in U$

and

exists $N \in E $ s.t. $n_i \ge N \implies x_{n_i} \in U$.

Then by definition, $K \le N \le n_i$  and so $x_{n_i} \in U$ and so exists $K \in D $ or exists $N \in E$ s.t. $n_i \ge K \implies x_{n_i} \in U$.

Thus we want $(x_\gamma)$ to converge on both $(D, \le')$ and $(E, \le '')$.

$2$:

Exists $\gamma_1 \in D $ s.t. $\gamma \ge \gamma_1 \implies x_\gamma \in U$. Fix this $\gamma_1$. Then by definition, $D_0 = \{\gamma \in D: \gamma \ge \gamma_1\}$ and so for all $\omega \in D_0$, we have $x_\omega  \in U$ meaning $(x_\gamma)$ converges on $D_0$.

Do the answers above work? Thanks.

edit:

rewrite for $(2)$:

As $D_0$ inherits the order $\le$ from $D$, it follows $D_0$ is also directed and s0 $\gamma_0 \le \gamma_1 \le \gamma_2 \le \ldots \le \gamma_k \le \ldots$ holds for the elements in $D_0$. Now by definition of $D_0$ we have $\gamma_k \in D_0$ and by assumption we have $\gamma \ge \gamma_1 \implies x_\gamma \in U.$ Thus $\gamma (\ge \gamma_k) \in D_0 \implies \gamma \ge \gamma_1 \implies x_\gamma \in U.$ If $\gamma (< \gamma_k) \in D_0$, then the smallest possible value for $\gamma$ is $\gamma = \gamma_1$ by assumption(definition of convergence of $(x_\gamma))$. Otherwise, there is some $j$ with $2 \le j < k$ s.t. $\gamma_2 \le \gamma_j \le \gamma.$ In either case, $x_\gamma \in U.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in 1. $D$ does not matter as $E$ is cofinal in $D \cup E$. In fact $(x_\gamma)_{\gamma \in D \cup E}$ converges to $p$ iff $(x_\gamma)_{\gamma \in E}$ converges to $p$, or more simply put a net $f: D \cup E \to X$ converges to $p$ iff $f\restriction_E$ does.

For 2. you need to explicitly invoke the directness of $D$ to find a $\gamma_2$ so that $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_0$ and use that $\gamma_2$ for $U$ (when $\gamma_1$ works for $U$ in the larger net).

So no, both your answers need corrections...

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, For $(2)$, We have $\gamma_1 \in D $ s.t. $\gamma \ge \gamma_1 \implies x_\gamma \in U$. But $D$ is directed and so there's some $\gamma_2 \in D$ s.t. $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_1.$ Fix this $\gamma_2$. Then by definition, $D_0 = \{\gamma \in D: \gamma \ge \gamma_2\}$ and so for all $\omega \in D_0$, we have $x_\omega  \in U$ meaning $(x_\gamma)$ converges on $D_0$. Does that work?

Comment: @user947160 No, $D_0= \{\gamma \in D; \gamma \ge \gamma_0\}$ and we know that $\gamma_2 \in D_0$ now. And if $\gamma \in D_0$ is also $\ge \gamma_2$, it's also $\ge \gamma_1$ and so $x_\gamma \in U$ etc. Be precise! $\gamma_0$ and thus $D_0$ is fixed, not dependent on $\gamma_2$.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, I edited my OP as there are too many characters to post it here. Please, see if that makes sense.

Comment: @user947160 Your new version is even more wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, regarding you previous comment,  $\gamma_2 \in D_0$ because $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_0$, right? Now if $\gamma \ge \gamma_2$ and $\gamma \in D_0$, then since $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_1$, we have $\gamma \ge \gamma_1?$ All this because $D_0$ is ordered by $\le$? This shows $x_\gamma \in U$. Then you say "etc". Does that mean we consider $\gamma_3$?

Comment: @user947160 yes, but no $\gamma_3$ is needed. And in your answer you suggest that $D_0$ is linearly ordered which need not be the case.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, we have $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_1 \ge \gamma_0$. How do we know that if $D_0$ isn't (at least partially?) linearly ordered? Also, what happens if $\gamma < \gamma_2$? Then $\gamma = \gamma_1$ and $x_\gamma \in U?$

Comment: @user947160 No, we only know $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_0$ and $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_1$ by directnedness. No relation between $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_0$ is known nor can be assumed.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, $\gamma_0, \gamma_1 \in D_0 \implies \exists \gamma_2 \in D_0$ with $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_0, \gamma_1$ by definition of directedness. Now I see $i$ in $\gamma_i$ is for bookkeeping, not linear ordering. We could've referred to $\gamma_0, \gamma_1, \gamma_2$ as $\gamma_7, \gamma_X, \gamma_{foo}$, respectively. We can't consider $\gamma < \gamma_2$ as $\le$ is an arbitrary quasiorder, not the regular $\le$ for comparing, say, integers. But what if $\gamma \le \gamma_2$? Does, then, $\gamma = \gamma_1$ or $\gamma = \gamma_0$? Does it cause contradiction?